# Is it possible in linux to change the input end of stdout of a running process?

Tags: linux, process

I have a linux process dumping unwanted data to stdout. But it also produces a log file with correct data. Can I point the stdout of this process to read from the log file and display it on the stdout?

Comment: you can redirect log file to stdout with tail command as  tail -f /path/file

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not specifically have stdout read data from another file in order to echo it to the screen.

What you could do, however, is dump stdout to /dev/null (since you don't need it), and instead tail the log file that contains the data you want to see.

**Example:**

In one terminal, run the program dumping stdout to /dev/null:
`./myProgram > /dev/null`

In another terminal:
`tail -f /var/log/logFile.log`